# How to remove duplicate row in a table in C# asp.net query

Tags: c#, asp.net, duplicates

I have two rows that have similar data in one table. And I want to remove the duplicate data between that two row which is from one table, how to remove it using C# ASP.NET query?

I use `distinct()` to remove the duplicate data, but it shows an error:

> 'The image data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable'

Here is my code:

```
var query = (from user in context.Users
             join group in context.Groups on user.ID equals group.UserID
             orderby user.Name
             where group.GroupID == nameID && user.IsDeleted == false || 
                   userGroup.GroupID == fullID && user.IsDeleted == false
             where user.IsDeleted == false
             select user);
```

This is the expected result:

[image]

but the result is like this:

[image]

It duplicate because of this, I need to show the data between the two row, and combine it as one.

```
where group.GroupID == nameID && userMaster.IsDeleted == false || userGroup.GroupID == fullID && user.IsDeleted == false
```

In SQL Server, I successfully removed the duplicate data as follows:

```
WITH CTE ([ID], [GroupID], [NameID], [Name], DuplicateCount) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (10) 
        [Group].ID, [GroupID], [NameID], [Name],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name asc) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM 
        [SCMD3].[dbo].[Group] 
    JOIN
        User ON Group.UserID = User.ID
    WHERE   
        (NameID LIKE '1' OR NameID LIKE '2') 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE DuplicateCount = 1
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

but how to remove it in C# code?

Comment: you can try something like:`context.Users.GroupBy(g => new { g.Name, g.NameId, g.GroupId }).SelectMany(s => s.Select((u, i) => new { Id = u.Id, Name = u.Name, NameId = u.NameId, GroupId = u.GroupId, Index = i + 1 })).Where(w => w.Index == 1).Select(s => new users { Id = s.Id, GroupId = s.GroupId, NameId = s.NameId, Name = s.Name }).ToList()`.

Comment: I honestly would not try to do everything in one step. You already have multiple `where`s and that's something where I would draw the line. I would leave the query as it is and filter out the duplicates with another expression. _Divide and Conquer_ seems to be a good strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` like so:

```
var partitioned = query.GroupBy(x => x.ID, x.GroupID, x.NameID, x.Name)
                  .SelectMany(g =>
                    g.Select((j, i) => new { j.ID, j.GroupID, j.NameID, j.Name, row_num = i + 1 }))
                  .Where(r => r.row_num = 1);
```

1. Group by all (or the required) columns,
2. Create a row_num column,
3. Filter all row_nums != 1

Answer (score -1):

If you have duplicate row then you can use "Skip" to remove the same, like the below

select user.Skip(1)

If you have more than two duplicate records, then you can use "Take(1)" also.

Hope this will help you.

Happy coding!!!!

Comment: it doesnt help. using skip(1) only remove first data only, and take(1) will only show one data from list